# How do I code a jpeg image of a group photo of my son's soccer team to pop-up info on individual players?

Tags: modal-dialog, jpeg

I have a group photo of my son's soccer team. I'd like to learn how to code this .jpeg image as a web page that can display information (in a small dialog box) about each individual player upon rolling over that individual.

For example, if the web page is presented to you and roll over the goal keeper, it would display his name, position, age, and various notes. As soon as you move the cursor to another player, information on that player would pop-up in another dialog box. Of course, only ONE (the current active) dialog box would be shown.

I'm a newbie, so please be gentle as I would need very explicit step-by-step instructions.

I've attached an example of the team photo.

[SOCCER TEAM PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxPCy.jpg)

Comment: This really is not a JPEG question. You need something else to do the popups.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and don't have an idea of how to best ask the question. Though, I learn fast, Do you have any idea what type of code/tool I can employ to get this type of result off an image?

Comment: How are you trying to display this? On the web?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to display this on the web.

Comment: That's probably going to be something like PHP or Javascript.

Comment: Anyone know where i can find this code already written so that I can cut and paste it?